# What is the role of "Gone" in below sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

In this sentence: "Thank you for bringing me on board. I know that I have very big shoes to fill with Mr. Williams gone, but I promise to do my best to live up to his legacy."

I don't understand the " gone" here. It is supposed to be a Noun after With. So is " gone" being a noun here?
Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

"Gone" is past participle. It describes Mr Williams as being "not here any more".

The "noun after with" is "Mr Williams" (a proper noun)

There are lots of similar structures such as

> ... with Mr Willians in America ...

> ... with Mr Williams partying every day ...

> ... with Mr Williams too tired to work ...

Comment: I would say that "Noun after with" is a misunderstanding: what must follow "with" is a nominal phrase - here, the participial phrase "Mr Williams gone". Referring to "Mr Williams" as "the noun after with" is misleading.